# SQL Server Currency Conversion Table Build, Iterate Over Collations?

Tags: sql-server-2008, special-characters, money-format

Using MSSQL 2008.

I looked around a bit online for a table that maps ISO 4217 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency names to their respective symbols, so I could map "840" to "$". I didn't find anything so I am about to build my own.

Is there a way to iterate over the different collations in the server and pull out the currency symbol (maybe they are all in the same charcode position) so I can get the right character to go with the numeric value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use nvarchar to isolate yourself from code page (which is ASCII 128 to 255) pretty much

And this page maps 3 letter codes to unicode symbols: http://www.xe.com/symbols.php 
The rest should be straightforward